# Importing JSON into Sketch App

Tags: json, sketch-3, sketchapp

I've managed to isolate the `json` structure of a specific Symbol by looking into the new Sketch open format file.

How can I now re-import it into a new Sketch file with a simple drag&drop? It seems like Sketch doesn't accept the `json` file as an input.

I've been trying to have a look at how some other apps like Craft and Lingo handle this, but I wasn't unable to inspect their source code.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be to check out the official documentation from Sketch.

https://developer.sketch.com/reference/api/

You would have to make a script that takes the JSON and creates a new symbol and adds this to a page.

Create a new symbol master:
https://developer.sketch.com/reference/api/#create-a-new-symbol-master

Add it to a page
https://developer.sketch.com/reference/api/#page

Also, this plugin describes already a bit how you could do the drag and drop behavior.
https://github.com/romannurik/Sketch-Stickers

Further a good place to start for plugins is: https://skpm.io/

For debugging I would recommend: https://github.com/skpm/sketch-dev-tools